# Error C1083 Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\..\..\Downloads\lua-5.1.5\lua-5.1.5\src\lua.c': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, lua

I've been working on a lua project but when i debug it i get errors that it can't find the files  http://prntscr.com/b3fy62

Any help would be appreciated (i download lua-5.1.5)

Comment: provide more information. where are those files on your computer. what did you do until you got this error message?

Comment: hi, the files are at "Downloads" and "Dekstop" i got the source from my friend i was working with. it works for him but not for me.. a bit later i got the CL.exe error which i have no idea on how to fix.

Comment: did you update your project settings so it will use your paths and not your friend's?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: provide more information on your toolchain and how you set up that stuff